# Excel VBA: If value not found in range, go to

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to loop through sheets 1-31 filtering each sheet by the value in a cell("E1") in sheets("RunFilter_2") and then copy the filtered range and copy to the next empty row in sheets("RunFilter_2").

The code errors when it doesn't find the value of sheets("RunFilter_2").Range("E1") in column 18 of the active sheet.

So I added a range check, that checks if sheets("RunFilter_2").Range("E1").Value is found in column Range("R:R").

But, how do I move to the Next I If rngFound Is Nothing?

```
Sub RunFilter2()

Rows("5:5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("A1").Select

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.sheets("01")

         Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim I As Integer

         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 3

         For I = 1 To WS_Count

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

sheets(I).Select

Columns("A:U").Select

Dim rng As Range
Dim rngFound As Range

Set rng = Range("R:R")

Set rngFound = rng.Find(sheets("RunFilter_2").Range("E1").Value)

If rngFound Is Nothing Then

'----------------------------------
' How do I code ... GO TO Next I
'----------------------------------

Else:

Selection.AutoFilter

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=sheets("RunFilter_2").Range("E1").Value

    Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Select
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

sheets("RunFilter_2").Select

If Range("A4").Value = "" Then

Range("A4").Select

Else

Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

End If

ActiveSheet.Paste
ws.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("A1").Select
sheets("RunFilter_2").Select

         Next I

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place some label before `Next I`:

```
NextI:
    Next I
```

Then you can do this:

```
If rngFound Is Nothing Then
    Goto NextI
Else
    ....
```

Alternatively you can simplify it without needing the else statement

```
If rngFound Is Nothing Then Goto NextI
.... ' Proceed without the need for `Else` and `End If`
```

EDIT.. Some more

While it is generally considered bad programming practice to use `Goto` statements, it is not the case in this specific situation. It is just used as a workaround for the lack of the `continue` statement that exists in the C and derived languages.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
For I = 1 To WS_Count
    If rngFound Is Nothing Then goto NextIPlace
    your code
NextIPlace:
Next I
```

But you should reconsider writing like this, it is not a good VBA practice to use `GoTo`. The whole code should be changed. [Check more here](https://www.google.com/search?q=goto%20bad%20practice&oq=goto%20bad%20&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.1791j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Once your code works, feel free to submit it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, they would give you good ideas.

Comment: Hi Vityata, I agree that in general the use of `Goto` statements is not a good programming practice, but not in this specific case. Other languages usually have statement to break or continue the loops (i.e. `continue` in the C family). VBA not having this option is sometimes  tedious and using this workaround might make the code more readabale. Just my humble opinion :)

Comment: @A.S.H, I use `GoTo` more often than I would ever agree. And yes, VBA needs a way to break loops.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use `GoTo` here. The simple way to accomplish this is with the following:

```
For I = 1 To WS_Count

    ' do stuff 

    If Not rngFound is Nothing

       'execute desired action

    End If

    ' do more stuff

Next i
```

You can also place the `do more stuff` inside the first if block if needed. The code in your post was kind of messy and I didn't take time to dissect fully.

Comment: I was about to talk about spaghetti programs with GoTo! I was about to do the same suggestion but I'd add a boolean to avoid `doing more stuff` regarding the structure of the OP! ;)

Comment: You can also code it as rngfound IsNot Nothing, which may or may not be a little clearer...

Answer (score 2):

you should add a marker before `Next I`

```
MARKER:
Next I
```

So after `If rngFound Is Nothing Then` you add `GoTo MARKER`